# Connect from pgadmin after upgrading to scram-sha-256 password authentication

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to configure scram-sha-256 for password authentication.
I changed postgresql.conf to:

```
password_encryption = scram-sha-256
```

I upgraded the passwords using `\password`
I then changed pg_hba.conf to:

```
local all all scram-sha-256
```

Doing all that I could start postgres and connect from psql using the upgraded password.

However, I cannot login from PGadmin, even though in my postgresql.conf it is configured for:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I get this error:

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

If I try to change to this in pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all all scram-sha-256
```

then postgres start fails with:

```
2020-01-02 11:54:17.046 IST [1] CONTEXT:  line 85 of configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"
2020-01-02 11:54:17.046 IST [1] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

What is the correct way then to enable both scram-sha-256 and connection from pgadmin?

Comment: What is your pgAdmin version?

Comment: ADDRESS column does not accept `ALL` as value, at least it is not listed as such in description of that configuration file. Maybe `0.0.0.0/0` would work instead.

Comment: Thank, will try it